# Is there a way to call the Modifier menu with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: interface, customization, shortcut

I was thinking it would be nice to be able to call the Modifier menu as a contextual menu using a keyboard shortcut. However, the drop-down button doesn't have any Python name listed in its Tool Tip. It just says "Add a Modifier to the Active Object".

[image: No Python listing for the Modifier menu dropdown button]

Is there a Python name and it's just not listed, or can this menu not be brought up contextually? Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

A custom keyboard shortcut can be set up to call `object.modifier_add`, and that will make the menu appear. I've set mine up in the Object Mode shortcuts section, and am using <kbd>F</kbd> for modi**F**ier.

[image: A custom keyboard shortcut for bringing up the Add Modifier menu]

And here's the result:

[image: The Add Modifier menu appearing at the cursor location]

The Add Modifier menu will conveniently appear at your cursor location within the 3D Viewport.

Answer (score 2):

Not that I can directly answer the question, but I do know that the way I call the menu is from the spacebar search, typing 'add m..' and then I click on 'add modifier' and the menu pops up in screen. The reason it doesn't seem to be able to add a shortcut to it is that it is about context, and the modifier panel only appears in the properties area when you have an object selected that can be given a modifier.

Comment: Thanks! That gave me the hint I needed to figure out what to do. I have the answer now! Will post in a sec.