# How to pop up this command" object.modifier_add"

Tags: python

[image: That's my answer.cause i am a new guy in this form.i cant find another way to reply this question after being deleted comment by moderator.thks all guys.if you want to know how to change the keyboard shortcut.contact me]I could not run the command `object.modifier_add` [as explained here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49134/is-there-a-way-to-call-the-modifier-menu-with-a-keyboard-shortcut). What's up with this?

[image: That is the problem]

Comment: the linked page shows that there is a pop menu to set up shortup for "add_modifier" and I can't pop it up. How should i do ??Thanks

Comment: Using the instructions from linked page I can make the menu appear, so define *what* doesn't work / isn't clear for you - on step of opening User Prefs window, on step of searching for appropriate context for the shortcut, etc. See also https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2449/1245 and please format your questions in a bit more clear way, you can [edit] it to add any info.

Comment: means i cant pop up the shortcuts setting menu,  i run the script in python  console with the command “objects.modifier_add",and no menu mentioned in the linked page poped up

Comment: Where does it suggest _run `object.modifier_add`  in python console_? Be like putting milk in your petrol tank and wondering why your car wont start.  Add it in the [keymap editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/preferences/input.html#keymap-editor)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to call the Modifier menu with a keyboard shortcut?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49134/is-there-a-way-to-call-the-modifier-menu-with-a-keyboard-shortcut)

Comment: emmmm...... ,seem you R right. so I find the keymap editor- - .however,it

Comment: I finished the answer .Thks to :Mr Zak ;batFINGER & orgin editor Mentalist.thk you~     // the problem i will post a pic under this page.

Comment: the final answer i've upload a newest img above the last question picture.thk you ！

Answer (score 1):

The string you type in the shortcut configuration screen is not Python code. It just happens to look somewhat similar to it. To run the operator as Python code, prefix it with `bpy.ops`, so `bpy.ops.object.modifier_add()`.

However, it's better to not use operators at all, and use a regular Python function instead:

```
bpy.context.active_object.modifiers.new('operatorname', 'BEVEL')
```

See [the documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_master/bpy.types.ObjectModifiers.html) for more info on all the operator type names. This function returns the new modifier, so you can set properties on it directly.

Comment: have voted your answer. it seems i find the solution,thkyou

Comment: cause i am a new guys.why i cant write another answer  instead of my last deleted one by moderator??...........So I cant past the answer here.emmmm...............